# Permission issue while viewing app on azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am running into this strange issue of not being able to view the web app once i try to browse it from azure. it gives me error by saying You do not have permission to view this directory or page. I don't know what going wrong. I simply created an app on azure and then using ftp client pushed a simple html page. When i try to browse it; it says you don't have permission although no login or permissions are set. This is a free trial subscription i wonder if this has to do something with it. I also tried to upload my node.js and angular web app but it gives the same issue. I even tried to change the port number to run the as in node we do. But now it doesn't even display a normal html page. I pasted it in WWW root folder using filezilla. Any idea how to go about it.

Comment: This is far too broad to get a specific answer. Please edit with specifics, such as where you uploaded the content (e.g. what specific directory, since you ftp'd instead of using some type of version control), what that simple content looked like, etc. Also it would be helpful to see your node.js code. One thing important is that you cannot arbitrarily choose a port (and only external ports 80 and 443 are supported in web apps). Oh, and then there's the assumption you're using an Azure Web App (please confirm in your edit).

Answer (score 0):

> it gives me error by saying You do not have permission to view this directory or page

It seems that there is no default page match the default documents in the Azure WebApp setting. You could add the default page for your webapp in the Azure portal Appsetting. Or you could upload a index.html to the WebApp for test.

[image]